# How to do custom pagination with non-orm model

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework 3 and I've run into some issues. I've gotten custom pagination working following [this example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#custom-pagination-styles) and I've gotten a non-orm model working following [this example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#declaring-serializers). However, I cannot get custom pagination (or any pagination, for that matter) working on a non-orm model. The custom pagination is set to default in settings.py and it works on all my viewsets with models.

The JSON output for endpoints with models includes the meta information and nests the objects within 'objects:'. The JSON output for endpoints without models just gives a list of the objects. My code is posted below. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Custom Pagination:

```
from rest_framework.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CustomPagination(LimitOffsetPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):       
        return Response({
            'meta': {
               'limit': self.get_limit(self.request),
               'next': self.get_next_link(),
               'offset': self.get_offset(self.request),
               'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
               'total_count': self.count
            },
            'objects': data
        })
```

Object:

```
class EMSEvent(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name, start, end):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
```

Serializer:

```
class EMSEventSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField()
    start = serializers.CharField()
    end = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
```

ViewSet:

```
class EMSEventViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = EMSEventSerializer(many=True)
    http_method_names = ['get']


    def list(self, request):
        results = []
        """
        Here is code that opens up a SQL connection, executes a   
        query, then transfers the data into results
        """

        # Always sort results by start time
        results = sorted(results, key=lambda k: k.start)
        serializer = EMSEventSerializer(instance=results, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

JSON Output for API Endpoints with models:

```
{
    meta: {
        limit: 20,
        next: "/api/v1/endpoint/?offset=20&limit=20&format=json",
        offset: 0,
        previous: null,
        total_count: 24
    },
    objects: [
        {
            description: "A Room",
            end: "2017-03-03T15:30:00",
            id: 1234,
            name: "Grad Day",
            resource_uri: "/api/v1/endpoint/1234/",
            room: "CMU Room",
            start: "2017-03-03T09:00:00"
        }
    ]    
}
```

JSON Output for API Endpoints without models

```
[
    {
        description: "A Room",
        end: "2017-03-03T15:30:00",
        id: 1234,
        name: "Graduate Day",
        resource_uri: "/api/v1/endpoint/1234/",
        room: "CMU Room",
        start: "2017-03-03T09:00:00"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working by modifying Swapril Mahajan's answer:

```
class EMSEventViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, CustomPagination):
    serializer_class = EMSEventSerializer(many=True)
    http_method_names = ['get']


    def list(self, request):
        results = []
        """
        Here is code that opens up a SQL connection, executes a   
        query, then transfers the data into results
        """

        # Always sort results by start time
        results = sorted(results, key=lambda k: k.start)
        page = self.paginate_queryset(results)
        serializer = EMSEventSerializer(instance=page, many=True)

        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Big Difference 1:

```
class EMSEventViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, CustomPagination):
```

I use a GenericViewSet as opposed to a ViewSet.  You have to use a ViewSet as opposed to a ModelViewSet to get it working with non-ORM data sources, and a GenericViewSet is apparently required to get that working with custom pagination.  Also, you have to pass in your custom pagination.

Big Difference 2:

```
serializer = EMSEventSerializer(instance=page, many=True)
```

I passed in page to the serializer as opposed to results.  I actually ended up testing it with instance=results and got the same outcome, but passing in instance=page makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

As you are overriding the default list method, you will have to paginate the response yourself. In that case you `list` method should be something like this

```
def list(self, request):
    results = []
    """
    Here is code that opens up a SQL connection, executes a   
    query, then transfers the data into results
    """

    # Always sort results by start time
    results = sorted(results, key=lambda k: k.start)

    # if paginate_queryset is not accessible in ViewSet then you can import it from paginator itself.
    page = self.paginate_queryset(results)

    serializer = EMSEventSerializer(instance=results, many=True)
    return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```